# Laravel - Can't fix my post function

Tags: laravel

This is my situation.
Please take a look to this picture to understand more.

[VUE APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjJLn.png)

I use to get input using axios and v-model from all textareas, except "nomencloture" which i need to get it from tests.

```php
public function addAccount(Request $request){
    $account = new Account;
    $account->nomencloture=$request->"I dont know what to write";
    $account->account_name=$request->account_name;
    $account->account_id=$request->account_id;
    $account->account_budget=$request->account_budget;
    $account->save();

    return response()->json(['etat'=> true]);

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can make your own nomenclature it empty

Comment: that my problem. i don't know how to give my nomenclature in comment the value of nomenclature in tests

Comment: I don't understand why and how you add that `tests`?

Comment: Can we please see your axios post code? Looking at how you are accessing those account inputs I am guessing that your post request is not including the _tests_ object as data.